# Title page disappears when put into seperate .tex-file

Tags: titles

so I'm quite new to Tex and writing my bachelor thesis with it.
Until today I only had a main.tex which had everything I coded in it.

For several reasons i decided to split every section into a separate file to make it easier to compile and so on.

Since I did this, my title page just vanished, but only if I try to include it on the titlepage. If the code for it is in the main.tex, everything works just fine... Maybe someone has an idea... Thanks everyone in advance.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\input{Packages}

\input{Meta}

\begin{document}
\include{Inhalt/Deckblatt}
\end{document}
```

The packages I use, that might be responsible, are:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
```

And the Meta.tex includes:

```
\title{Title}

\author{
  Name1\\
  \texttt{Email1}
  \and
  Betreuer: Name2\\
  \texttt{Email2}
}

\date{10.07.2023}
```

In the Deckblatt.tex is only the following code:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
```

Feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: The problem is not loading the page with `\include`. The problem seems to be the missing `\maketitle`. Please try to make a one-file [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) next time. BTW: Using`\include` instead of `\input` for the title page, IMHO seldom makes sense, because usually you won't use `\includeonly` to omit the title page.

Comment: So I minimalized the files, but I'm not sure, if my problem was exactly clear: The error only occurs, if I split the ```\maketitle``` into another file. If its in the main.tex it compiles just fine.

Comment: I'm absolutly sorry, I did a terrible minor spelling mistake, I just found. The code works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry everyone: I did a minor spelling mistake I just noticed. Now the code works just fine.

The `\include{Inhalt/Deckblatt}` was outdatet, I renamed the file a while ago and I didn't notice.